# RHEL 7 service kicks in immediately

Tags: linux, redhat

I am migrating an application from RHEL 6 to 7. In RHEL 6, I used chkconfig and in 7 I am attempting to use systemctl ( config shown below).
However, I noticed that if I stop the service using the actual command (instead of using systemctl stop ), the service gets started up automatically. I dont want this to happen. How do I disable this ?

```
[Unit]
Description=My service

[Service]
User=my_account
Group=my_account
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/some_location
ExecStart=/some_location/start_my_service.sh
ExecStop=/some_location/stop_my_service.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Why not use `systemctl stop`?

Comment: Why not ? Cos I work in an enterprise and I cannot control each and every command other users (who might even have root priv) may execute.

Comment: I remain confused. You want random other users using the wrong command to have an *easier* time stopping your service incorrectly?

Comment: I can see that you are very confused. Again, if you have not worked in a large enterprise it will be very hard for you to understand.

Comment: Sorry, this is BS. Having anyone starting/stopping services in whatever way they please is insane and has no place in a decent IT shop of any size and certainly not in a large enterprise.

Comment: @bubbly I've worked at a very large enterprise. Services, when they needed restarting, were restarted by qualified personnel, according to the proper, documented procedure.

Comment: You instruct the users to use the proper systemctl commands. Anything else is unprofessional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bad idea but you can force SystemD to not restart it with the line

```
Restart=no
```

in the service definition. See `man systemd.service` for more information about the options.

Comment: If I use this option, when I restart the server at the os level, will it startup the service ?

Comment: I am really looking for the same functionality as chkconfig

Comment: `systemctl start` should not enable the service, only start it, so if it is disabled, it would not be started. `systemctl enable/disable` is the replacement for `chckonfig on/off` and `systemctl start/stop` is the replacement for `service start/stop`.